# what is containership or nesting in C++?

Tags: c++, object

what i understood is:
Containership: a class contains another class objects as member data.

please explain with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Nah, a containership is a proud vessel which sails the ocean waves stuffed with big metal boxes.

Answer (score 6):

**Class nesting** is simply to have a class defined in another class, like that :

```
class A
{
public:
   class B 
   {
   public:
       class C{};
   };

};
```

Then you can access a nested class using the scope operator, like you would do with namespaces :

```
A a;
A::B b;
A::B::C c;
```

Now when a class **contain** another class's **object**, it's an **aggregation** :

```
class D
{
public:

   A myA;

   void do_something();

private:
   A::B myB;

};
```

Then you can access the member like that if it's public :

```
D d;
process( d.myA ); // access to myA
```

If it's not accessible, then you can provide it via a function. Anyway, inside the class functions, you can directly access the member :

```
void D::do_something()
{
    doit( myB );
    // or
    doit( this->myB );
}
```

Comment: a class contains another class **objects** as member data?

Comment: No, type nesting is about having types defined in (relative to) another type. Objects can be member (data) of classes, and their type can be anything. You're mixing two very different abstractions.

Answer (score 3):

**Containership** simply means an object can be accessed inside another.

For instance :

```
class Contained
{
    int foo;
};

class Container
{
    Contained bar;
};
```

You can access foo like this :

```
Container c;
c.bar.foo = 42;
```

**Class nesting** is different. It means you are declaring a class from inside another :

```
class AngryMammoth
{
    class CrazyVulture
    {
        int legCount;
    };

    int numberOfPeopleKilledSoFar;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class In {};
class Out {
  In object;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar to inheritance, an object of `class A` is embedded in the object of `class B`:

```
class A {
  int x;
};
class B {
  int y;
  A a1;
  A a2;
};
```

If you would instantiate `B b`, you would get something like this on your memory:

```
int y; // b.y
int x; // b.a1.x
int x; // b.a2.x
```

Contrary to a pointer attribute, a nested object actually sits inside the outer object. Also you do not have to worry about creating/deleting `A` as it is automatically done when `B` is created/deleted.

Comment: How, exactly, is this "Similar to inheritance"?

Comment: Well, if you consider what is actually sitting in the memory, it is crude inheritance. Whether you say `class B : public A {}` or `class B { public: A a; }` is only a syntactical difference, isn't it? Of course you do not have dynamic binding and such.

Comment: The differences are hugely important particularly to a new programmer who does not understand the difference between 'containership' [sic.] and nesting; yet you choose not to highlight them in your answer?

Comment: No I do not. Because the question was not `explain the difference between inheritance and aggregation`. It was `explain what's going on in aggregated data structures`. I felt it was an important aspect to note that these are **similar** (not at all equal!). On a side note: In languages that do not inherently support inheritance (e.g. C), you can get quite close by simply using aggregations (as long as you do not need dynamic binding).